# XCode class models: how to view Framework classes?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm using XCode 3.1.4, I'd like to browse the iOS framework classes visually, eg. the UIKit.framework classes.

I believe this is possible with Class Model facility, the documents here http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/xcodefuture.html suggest so:

> The Xcode class modeler works with Objective-C, C++, and Java source code files and can give you a look at just a few classes, every class in your project, or **even all of the classes in a framework**.

I made a Class Model and selected Add All to include everything including the framework's .framework files. However on the generated diagram where I see UITableViewCell, it has no arrows pointing up from it, even though I know this class inherits from UIView. I've played with clicking various ways, the menus and Info but can't see how to see the full inheritance tree of UITableViewCell.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question well. What do you mean by "browse the iOS framework classes visually" exactly ?

Comment: The Class Model facility is a visual browser for classes. Follow the links I provided if you are unsure. I would like to use this tool to look at the iOS framework classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did to make it work:

Select the project:
[image: proj]

Then choose Quick Model:
[image: quick model]

Then you get a ridiculously large model with all the classes in it.
[image: model]

If you wanted the classes from just one framework, you could select just that framework in the files list, instead of the whole project.

Comment: Were you able to see UIView as a UITableViewCell superclass?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing in the Xcode Class Modeler, so it may be an issue with the tool or a choice made by its authors.

Answer (score 0):

The method you used should give you a correct model, however you may need to move classes around to be able to see the arrows as there are way too many lines present if you model everything at once. The quick model will give the same results using the selection (i.e. if you select your project itself you get everything, and if you select a group of classes you will just get them.